# Problem running battle.net in wine 1.7

Tags: 14.04, wine

So, using 14.04 LTS, I ran the command shown in this [link](http://geebzor.com/tech/linux/wow-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/), to download wine 1.7, and the battle.net client, and everything installed fine. The problem is that a necessary dropdown menu won't work.

To sign in to battle.net you are required to select a region, but when you press the button to do so, the terminal says :

> "fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported"
>   "fixme:win:FlashWindowEx 0x33bc2c"

and the menu won't appear, so I can't progress any further.

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems this is a known Wine bug, with only a luck based workaround.

The dropdown menu does exist, and you can navigate it, you just can't see it.

If you're having this problem yourself, use the tab key to make sure the focus is on the region button, then use Up/Down arrows to navigate inside the invisible region menu, then press enter to select which ever region you got. Then it's just trial and error until you find your region.

Comment: Good answer, for me it works as long as I don't move the window before selecting region.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Linux, and I am using Mint and ran into the same exact problem, which brought me here.

I don't know if this will work for you, but I have a duel monitor set up. So I clicked the dropdown menu to select region, which obviously didn't work. So I held down tab and the menu itself popped up on my other monitor. Basically I just moved my mouse over to the right monitor and selected my region.

I don't know if this will help you at all. I was just thinking instead of the menu being invisible, for some reason it's popping up off screen instead of dropping down. Maybe I only noticed it because I have two monitors.

Comment: The same happened to me. I can select the dropdown menu using the tab key, then press space to open the dropdown. It popped up on my secondary monitor, where I could either use the mouse or use the up/down keys to select an entry.